# why do i get an exception while making a key stroke in the notepad?

Tags: c, windows, visual-studio, winapi, keyboard-hook

i have one solution file in visual studio, and i have in it two projects one for the .dll file and one other project to the .c file:

this is the .h file:

```
#include <windows.h>

#ifndef BHANNAN_TEST_CLASS_H_
#define BHANNAN_TEST_CLASS_H_

extern int __declspec (dllexport) Factorial(int n);

#endif
```

and in .c file (of the dll ):

```
#include "hanan.h"
#include <stdio.h>

int Factorial(int n) {
  printf("in DLL %d \n" ,n);

  return 0;
}
```

now i have a loader/tester which i try from it to load the dll to hook keystrokes in notepad, just to understand the mechanism of the hooking.

this is the code of the loader:

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <stdio.h>

typedef int (*functor) (int);
functor funcptr =NULL;

int main () {

    HWND windowHandle;
    HINSTANCE hMod;
    HOOKPROC lpfn; 
    DWORD threadId;
    HHOOK hook;
    HMODULE myDLL = LoadLibraryW(L"dll123.dll");
    funcptr = (functor) GetProcAddress(myDLL,"Factorial");

    /// printing issues:////////////////
    printf("%d \n\r" , myDLL);
    printf("%d" , funcptr(33));
    //////////////////////////////////////

    lpfn = (HOOKPROC) funcptr;
    hMod = myDLL;
    windowHandle = FindWindow(L"Notepad",NULL);
    threadId = GetWindowThreadProcessId(windowHandle, NULL);

    hook = SetWindowsHookEx(WH_KEYBOARD,lpfn,hMod,threadId);//(WH_CBT, HookCBTProc, hInst, threadId);

    /// printing issues:
    printf("%d %d %d %d\n" , hook, WH_KEYBOARD , lpfn , hMod);
    printf("%d %d \n",threadId , windowHandle );
    getchar();
    return 0;
}
```

i get all the printing no zeros, which means there are no nulls (assuming notepad is running), but when i do any keystroke in notepad i get an exception right away,

using visual studio 2010 and windows 7

added exception properties:

```
 Exception Offset:  0006632c
  Exception Code:   c0000409
  Exception Data:   00000000
```

Comment: Yet you don't mention the actual exception you're getting.

Comment: @p.campbell - Reading error messages spoils the fun.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just a shot in the dark, but the function that you pass to the set hook call should look like this:

```
LRESULT CALLBACK KeyboardProc(
  __in  int code,
  __in  WPARAM wParam,
  __in  LPARAM lParam
);
```

Not:
`int Factorial(int n)` (where are the two other params??)

Comment: Yes, this is the correct hook callback procedure signature. Using anything else is almost guaranteed to cause an exception.

Comment: how does it get the wParam and lParam? what are those parameters ?

Comment: Windows calls the routine, so your method "gets" them by being passed them. What's the meaning of them, I dunno - check MSDN ;) No matter what they are, you MUST declare your callback method correctly. I originally figured you had a calling convention problem, but I think it's simpler than that - just the prototype is wrong.